# Unable to disable radio buttons after another punching radio button

Tags: jquery

I have a radio button and a table of many radio buttons. I am punching radio button on page load.

and then on condition basis I am disabling the first radio button of every row in table. Below is the code I am using however neither radio button is punching nor others are getting disabled.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function
        $("#Q6x1_8").prop('checked',true);
        if($("#Q6x1_8").is(':checked'))
          $('tr td').find('input[type=radio']).first().prop('disabled',true);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type='radio' id='Q6x1_8'>Click<p>
<table border='1'>

<tr>
<td>Test1</td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test2</td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test3</td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test4</td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test5</td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test6</td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you `punching`? check/uncheck them

Comment: Are you trying to set the radio as selected on page load..? any reason why you can't set it in `html`..? So once it's checked, how are you planning to uncheck it..?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function` should be `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: @ShaunakD  I have to use this in one tool..to present the demo here I was checking it using jquery, my purpose is to check if the radio button is checked, if yes then disabling first radio button in every row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#Q6x1_8").prop('checked', true);
 if($("#Q6x1_8").is(':checked')) {
    $('tr td:nth-child(2)').children('input[type="radio"]').attr('disabled', true);
 }
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8hD9z/1/)

Comment: Thanks @Tilwin Joy, it worked for me, also can you please tell the use of "children"? will it refer to the 2nd element of every td?

Comment: nop, i was just about to add it as a side note, `find()` will search through all the descendants, (*child, grandchild, so on...*) `children()` will only search direct children (*light weight*), since we know that radio is a direct child of `<td>`, it's better to use children for performance...

Answer (score 0):

- `$(document).ready(function` should be
  `$(document).ready(function(){`
- There won't be any use of `if` condition it would always be true.

Use this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Q6x1_8").prop('checked', true);

    $('tr').each(function () {
        $(':radio:first',this).prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mqXLU/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function
        $("#Q6x1_8").prop('checked',true);
        if($("#Q6x1_8").is(':checked'))
          $('tr td input:radio:first').prop('disabled',true);
    });
```

do this way

Comment: Thanks it worked for me but I want to disable the first radio button for every row.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a loop like this:

**js**

```
$("#Q6x1_8").prop('checked',true);

    $("table tr").each(function(){
            if($("#Q6x1_8").is(':checked'))
                $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').first().prop('disabled',true);
                    });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5XXNN/7/)

Alternative you can use a checkbox and enable/disable `radios` if `checkbox` is checked or not:

```
$("#Q6x1_8").on("change", function(){
    $("table tr").each(function(){
            if($("#Q6x1_8").is(':checked'))
                $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').first().prop('disabled',true);
            else
                $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').first().prop('disabled',false);
                    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5XXNN/11/)

Comment: Thanks, is there any other short way instead of loop?

Comment: Yes. Look at @Tilwin Joy answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use nth-child to select element

```
$('tr td:nth-child(2) :radio').prop('disabled', true);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8hD9z/3/)